# PHP: If Statement, why was else executed before adding return?

Tags: php

In the below code I wanted to check if a value existed. If it did exist, then if one number was bigger than a second number I wanted to do something. If it was not bigger I wanted to do nothing. If the value did not exist I wanted to do something else.

The code did not work the way I expected until I added `return;`

Before adding `return;` if the value existed but number one was not bigger than number two then the `else` would still happen.

Here is the layout of the code:

```
if ( $value ) { 
    if ( $number_one > $number_two ) {
    // Do something
    }
    // Do nothing
    return;
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

I had a feeling I'd need to add something like `return;` to solve the issue but I didn't find many examples of it being used while searching for the answer.

I still don't specifically know why I needed to add it.

Thanks

Comment: `if ( $value )` checks if `$value` is not any interpretation of 0, otherwise it will execute your `else`-block. But your current code should not be correct PHP at all, as you have a stray `else`-block.

Comment: Are you `return`Ing a value from a function or method?  No? There’s no reason for a return then.  When the script encounters a `return `, it immediately returns to the context that called it. So you effectively stopped your script right there.

Comment: @csabinho I understood that `if ( $value )` would check as you mentioned. I'll check the outcome again and make sure it is processing the way I think it is. How is the `else` block stray?

Comment: what's in with the `$value` ?

Comment: Can't really reproduce your issue: https://3v4l.org/uc8KW

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't see a bracket, it's not stray at all!

Comment: @TimMorton yes, it seems the return was the first trial and error I encountered that gave me the outcome I was looking for but didn't actually solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: @fmsthird I am using `$wpdb->get_var` to check if there is a `NULL` value in a column.

Comment: have you tried using `PHP isset() function` instead to check if a variable `$value` is declared and is not null?

Comment: @fmsthird no, but as I was writing my reply to you I realised my issue is likely with the value I am checking. I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: @DanielSpark what's the secrecy with this code i dont get. Why are you showing a commented layout? This eerily looks like what an instructor would provide as a *template* to actually solving a problem. Doesn't look like a casual *layout* you're providing for us mere mortals.

Comment: @GetSet no intention of secrecy. As my question was about the way the `if` was operating I removed what it will do as it wasn't relevant. I was trying to be clear in what I thought the issue was. However, I see now providing everything else would have allowed anyone reading to catch issues I don't even know I have. I'll keep it in mind for the future. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielSpark Sometimes a bunch of code can be a hassle to inspect, agreed, but only if poorly written in terms of identifiers (var names and such). Your comments in your *layout* however are well executed. Was curious is all why not post the code, at least in conditionals. No, not only conditionals, everything. The comments are too spot on not to.